# what will happen when vector<unique_ptr<T>> resize?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, smart-pointers

A vector will copy its elements to another memory location and free previous mems when resizing (right?) However, copy constructor of unique_ptr is deleted; So I guess they will be moved instead of copied.

Q:

1. I am not sure if there are concepts like shallow/deep-move similar to shallow/deep-copy.
2. I was wondering the copy or move behavior is determined by the vector class definition, or by how you overload copy or move constructor of the element class you pushed in vector.

Comment: `I am not sure if there are concepts like shallow/deep-move similar to shallow/deep-copy.` Move specifically exists to prevent deep copying. A deep move wouldn't make any sense whatsoever.

Comment: *"A vector will copy its elements to another memory location and free previous mems when resizing (right?)"* -- not exactly. The vector will try to move its elements, and if that fails (or if moving might throw an exception) it falls back to copying. (You have the roles of copying and moving reversed.) I don't think this materially impacts your question, though.

Comment: @JaMiT: That was my first guess too, but in [this example (godbolt)](https://godbolt.org/z/8Ez8rbcPG), we have both a move and a copy constructor, and the copy constructor is chosen?  But if we comment out the copy constructor, [then we get the move](https://godbolt.org/z/rYMavxqE9).  Or have I done something silly?

Comment: @NateEldredge Mark the move constructor `noexcept`.